# Triggered Blend animation on page's loaded event fired too early

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, blend

I'm having issues as I'm trying to start storyboard animation when application starts. I have fast storyboard animation (0.5 seconds), attached to main page's `Loaded` event via `EventTriggerBehavior` in Blend which starts storyboard animation. But almost every time application (after hiding splash screen) animation is already done.

Here is my XAML (for WP8.1; but same applies for 8.1 store application):

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:OnloadAnimation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
    x:Class="OnloadAnimation.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="OnloadStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="5"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="367.164">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="5"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="5"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="400">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="5"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource OnloadStoryboard}"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid Background="#FF1D1D1D">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerPressed">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource OnloadStoryboard}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Also here is [full solution](http://cirno.in/~stack-overflow/OnloadAnimation.zip).

Comment: Does RT have BeginTime to set a delay?